# Identify the latitudinal and longitudinal point directly beneath an object in space

Tags: coordinate-system, algorithm, spherical-geometry, satellite

Given the `azimuth and altitude` / `latitude and longitude` from the observer to the satellite, **how can I accurately find the latitude and longitude of the point of intersection directly under the satellite?**

[image]

I also have the L1/2 p and L1/2 c/a values.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you have the distance from the observer to the satellite--without which the problem has no definite solution--then this amounts to solving three subproblems, using the strategy of computing the satellite's geocentric Cartesian (x,y,z) coordinates.

In the following, *a* is the semimajor axis (6,378,137.0 meters in [WGS 84](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System#A_new_World_Geodetic_System:_WGS_84)) and *b* is the semiminor axis (approximately 6,356,752.314 245 meters).  All calculations should consistently use either radians or degrees--whatever is preferred for trigonometric functions by your software.  Double-precision calculations will give sub-micron accuracy, assuming such accuracy is present in the original data!

The (working) examples use *Mathematica*.

#### Convert between geodetic and Cartesian coordinates

We may parameterize a vertical cross-section of the ellipsoid in the form (x, z) = (a * cos(t), b * sin(t)) for the latitude *t*, and then rotate it around the z axis.  Inverting the equations enables us to recover (lon, lat) from (x,y,z).

```
ellipsoidToCartesian[{lon_, lat_}, {a_,b_}] := {a Cos[lat] Cos[lon], a Cos[lat] Sin[lon], b Sin[lat]};
cartesianToEllipsoid[{x_, y_, z_}, {a_,b_}] := {ArcTan[x, y], ArcTan[Norm[{x, y}]/a, z/b]};
```

#### Obtain a basis for the tangent plane at any point

This code returns a list whose first element is the origin and whose second element is the orthonormalized basis {east, north, up}.  It computes the derivatives of the geodetic parameters and normalizes them to obtain a basis for the tangent plane, then uses their cross product to calculate the unit "up" vector.

```
tangent[{lon_, lat_}, {a_, b_}] := Module[{north, east, up},
  north = {-a Cos[lon] Sin[lat], -a Sin[lat] Sin[lon], b Cos[lat]};
  north = north / Norm[north];
  east = {-a Cos[lat] Sin[lon], a Cos[lat] Cos[lon], 0};
  east = east / Norm[east];
  up = Cross[east, north];
  {ellipsoidToCartesian[{lon, lat}, {a, b}], {east, north, up}}
  ]
```

#### Compute the satellite's Cartesian coordinates

The altitude and azimuth, along with the distance from the observer, are essentially local spherical coordinates.  Converting them into a vector displacement gives the satellite's coordinates relative to the observer's location.

The altitude and azimuth are relative to a local coordinate system based on (east, north, up).  The following presumes the azimuth is given east of north.

```
satellite[{azimuth_, altitude_}, {lon_, lat_}, elevation_, {a_, b_}] := 
  Module[{origin, east, north, up},
   {origin, {east, north, up}} = tangent[{lon, lat}, {a, b}];
   elevation (east Sin[azimuth] Cos[altitude] + 
       north Cos[azimuth] Cos[altitude] + up Sin[altitude]) + origin
   ];
```

#### The solution

Having obtained the satellite's Cartesian coordinates, we are done, because all that is needed is to convert them back to the geodetic coordinates.

```
position[{azimuth_, altitude_}, {lon_, lat_}, elevation_, {a_, b_}] := 
 Module[{xyz},
  xyz = satellite[{azimuth, altitude}, {lon, lat}, elevation, {a, b}];
  cartesianToEllipsoid[xyz, {a, b}]
  ]
```

A dynamic visualization confirms all this works as intended.  A line segment drawn from the origin (gray) to the satellite (blue) indeed coincides with the computed satellite coordinates (red).

[image]

For the convenience of those who may have access to *Mathematica*, code for the visualization follows.

```
Module[{world, azimuth, altitude, lon, lat, elevation, a = 1, s, p, o},
 Manipulate[
  world = 
   ParametricPlot3D[
    ellipsoidToCartesian[{lon, lat}, {1, b}], {lon, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, {lat, -\[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/2}, 
    PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5], MeshFunctions -> {#4 &, #5 &}, 
    MeshStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.5], Gray], Boxed -> False];
  s = satellite[{azimuth, altitude}, {lon, lat}, elevation, {a, b}];
  p = ellipsoidToCartesian[cartesianToEllipsoid[s, {a, b}], {a, b}];
  o = ellipsoidToCartesian[{lon, lat}, {a, b}];
  Show[Graphics3D[{
     Thick, Line[{{0, 0, 0}, s}], Line[{o, s}], 
     PointSize[0.02], Gray, Point[{0, 0, 0}], Green, Point[o], Blue, Point[s], Red, Point[p]
     }, Boxed -> False], world],
  {{azimuth, 0, "Azimuth"}, 0, 2 \[Pi]},
  {{altitude, \[Pi]/2, "Altitude"}, 0, \[Pi]/2},
  {{lon, 0, "Longitude"}, -\[Pi], \[Pi]},
  {{lat, \[Pi]/3, "Latitude"}, -\[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/2},
  {{elevation, 1, "Distance"}, 0, 2},
  {{b, 1, "b/a"}, 0, 1}
  ]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd try to translate this to cartesian coordinates:
The observer is at $(R \cos \phi \cos \lambda, R\cos\phi R \sin \lambda, R \sin \phi)$ with $R=$ Earth radius, $\lambda=$ longitude, $\phi=$ latitude.
Next, azimuth and altitude (measured against the tangent at the observer) determine a line and with the elevation you get a quadratic with two solutions (one is "behind" the observer in the wrong direction), thus the position $(x,y,z)$ of the satellite in space. Finally, $\frac z{H+R}$ is the sine of the latitude and $\frac y x$ is the tangent of the longitude.

Comment: The last part of this solution is correct only when working with a perfectly spherical model of the earth will be adequate.  (Errors up to a few tens of kilometers are possible.)