# How to project geographic coordinates to cartesian with the least possible error?

Tags: coordinate-system, convert, google-earth

I need to convert geographic coordinates (in decimal degrees) to cartesian with the least possible error?  I searched a lot on the internet but it seems that the conversion is not exact. Could you please present a **conversion formula** with the least possible error? I am working on a set of data including hospital locations obtained by Google earth.

---

I am working on a mathematical problem and the hospital locations is just an input parameter for the problem. If the  error is less that a few meters it is absolutely acceptable. I just need to project the (long,lat) coordinates to a 2-dimensional cartesian coordinates.  Is the following formula usually used for the conversion? 
x = R * cos(lat) * cos(lon)
y = R * cos(lat) * sin(lon)
 I saw that different sources consider different values for R! what value is better? Some other sources say that this formula is not appropriate as the earth is not an exact sphere!

Comment: Which Cartesian system are you using? How low does the error need to be? Typically the error is of the order a few metres - google earth imagery often isn't that accurate, and hospitals are almost always much larger than a few metres?

Comment: Any good answer will need information about (a) the set of locations and (b) how you would measure the *total* error for those locations. Please edit your question accordingly. You can find out more about the science of map projections and how to select them (and even design your own) by searching our site or the Web.

Comment: Thanks BradHards, whuber and radouxju for your concern. I am working on a mathematical problem and the hospital locations is just an input parameter for the problem.If the  error is less that a few meters it is absolutely acceptable. Is the following formula usually used for the conversion? 
x = R * cos(lat) * cos(lon)
y = R * cos(lat) * sin(lon)
z = R *sin(lat)

Comment: You need to explain more. What is the coordinate frame for x, y, z, R, lat and lon? If lat and lon are measured on a sphere, then that is different to measurements on an ellipsoid. Because there are many coordinate frames, you need to include this detail in your question. You still haven't answered any of our questions - please edit the question again.

Comment: The formulas for converting between (geocentric 3D) Cartesian coordinates and geographic coordinates (relative to an ellipsoid) are provided in my answer at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34532/identify-the-latitudinal-and-longitudinal-point-directly-beneath-an-object-in-sp/34534#34534.

Comment: If you know the input and best output crs (which is not difficult to find and depends on which part on earth you are), almost any GIS software will easily do it. Do you have to do it yourself?

Comment: Don't worry about about formulas until you further understand the basic concepts of map projections.

This could help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection

Answer (score 1):

For plane cartesian coordinates, it will depend on the projected coordinate sytem that you are using. But if you use a plane coordinate system based on the same geographic coordinate system than your decimal degrees, then you have an exact conversion. Otherwise, the error mainly comes from the definition of the height above the ellipsoid, but this error can be neglected if you are location building like hospitals (it is far less than 1 m). The large inaccuracies often come from not converting between 2 geographic CRS. Again, these tranformation depend on your input and output CRS.

Comment: That doesn't actually answer the question, which asked for a conversion formula.

Comment: @BradHards -- It's the best answer to a poorly conceived question.