# Calculate ground nadir line from PV coordinates

Tags: remote-sensing, satellite

I'm using [an API](https://www.orekit.org/) which returns a satellite's PVCoordinates (Position/Velocity pairs).

```js
{P(1036869.5330731269, 6546536.584960848, 9.892293545390519E-11), V(-9994.355195123433, 1582.9503539842497, -1242.4491245907245)}
```

**Given an array of these PV coordinates, how can I calculate or derive latitude and longitude coordinates for the nadir line (ground sub-track)?**

Does anyone know of a Java API which might help me or is the math easy enough that I can write a function myself? (Full Disclosure: I have a math disorder)

[image: Nadir line example]

I've looked around the web and everything I see tends to make my eyes glaze over and humble me to the point of wishing my pathetic self should have taken more math in college.

Comment: Doesn't the thread at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34532/identify-the-latitudinal-and-longitudinal-point-directly-beneath-an-object-in-sp answer this? Although it is in principle possible to use the velocity data to improve the plot of a track when the data are sparse, I can assure you the math will get harder :-).  You need only a small part of my answer there: the (one-line) `CartesianToEllipsoid` function.

Comment: Have a look at the [Orekit Corridor Track example](https://www.orekit.org/forge/projects/orekit/repository/revisions/master/entry/src/tutorials/java/fr/cs/examples/propagation/TrackCorridor.java).  Around line 275 the sub-satellite track is computed.

Comment: @rickhg12hs Please copy/past your comment as an answer so I can give you credit. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help!  Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Orekit Corridor Track example](https://www.orekit.org/forge/projects/orekit/repository/revisions/master/entry/src/tutorials/java/fr/cs/examples/propagation/TrackCorridor.java) shows how to calculate the sub-satellite track around line 275.

Comment: Works perfectly.